# React JS external hyperlink to a html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

After building my react app no edits works unless it's done in app.bundle.js(the build js file) and I need to give an external (a href) link to a file (html) which is in my device. how may I write that linking code?
I have written this code(the format is same as it is in the build js file)

```
_react2.default.createElement(
                'li',
                null,
                _react2.default.createElement(
                  _reactScroll.Link,
                  { href : 'https://www.google.com'},
                   // window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
                  _Localization2.default.strings.privacypolicy

                )
              ),
```

Just in place of "Google.com" the end result should be a file name (html) that is stored in my pc.